# Extracting a particular Project ID from Asana Task API via Node.js JSON output

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, asana, asana-api

Using the [Asana Task API](https://developers.asana.com/docs/get-a-task), we're able to see the list of projects that a task belongs to, as well as those projects' GID and Notes (description text).

## Desired outcome

The entire goal here is to grab the GID of the project that has #websiteprojecttemplate within its Notes value. We need to find the GID of that project, and then output it so we can use that GID later on in our Zapier actions.

### Asana Task API

Using this API URL, we can see the output of the API which returns the data of the projects (including the GID and Notes). I believe this is JSON. `https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/{id}?opt_fields=projects.notes`

**For example:**
`https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/1799885428032109?opt_fields=projects.notes` shows as:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/zSizMNC.png]

---

## Current code

Ideally, the Node.js Javascript code would be able to iterate/search/find the one with `#websiteprojecttemplate` and then output the matching GID. In this case, it'd be: `1199916857565229`

**This is the JS code I have so far:**

```
const res = await fetch('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/' + inputData.uniqueID + '?opt_fields=projects.notes', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer 0/899removedforsecurity24564s'
    }
});
const body = await res.json();
const projects = body.data;

output = { id: projects };
```

**Which outputs something like:**

```
  "id" : {
    "gid" : "1199885428032109",
    "projects" : [ {
      "gid" : "810573962916457",
      "notes" : "CRM project to create custom fields for the CRM task"
    }, {
      "gid" : "881219806802782",
      "notes" : "Helps keep PMs aware of what stage of progress the website projects are at; as well as how many projects each PM has (via saved Asana searches)."
    }, {
      "gid" : "1129624391492919",
      "notes" : "Tracks the stage and progress of converting a lead to a client."
    }, {
      "gid" : "1140671985497468",
      "notes" : "Additional CRM project to create more custom fields for the CRM task"
    }, {
      "gid" : "1199916857565229",
      "notes" : "Created from the #websiteprojecttemplate."
    } ]
  }
```

But I need it to output not the entire body's data, but only the `gid` value that had `#websiteprojecttemplate` in its `notes` value.

---

## TL;DR

How do we update the current code so that it can iterate through the `gid` and find the one that has `#websiteprojecttemplate` in the `notes`, and output the `gid` number of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question boils down to how to find an element in an array.

```
const project = projects.projects.find(p => p.notes.includes("#websiteprojecttemplate"));
if (project) {
  console.log(project.gid);
} else {
  console.log("no matching project");
}
```

Comment: This seems to work well. Out of curiosity, why use `p` instead of `project`? Is it just shorter? What if another key ended up in the API output at some point that started with a p?

Comment: This part `p => p.notes.includes("#websiteprojecttemplate")` is a function which takes a parameter p and returns a true/false value.  The parameter name can be anything and is not tied to the properties in the array that .find is operating on.  And yes, it'

Comment: And yes its shorter :)